# Ubuntu 10.04 is not booting and turns to blank screen - cannot login

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

My Ubuntu 10.04 beta turns into black screen when I start it up. I see the Purple Ubuntu loading for less than a second, then it turns into blank black screen and nothing happens after, cannot use it or login.

I restarted it twice for updates, and it worked.
I hibernated it (didn't work) so I forced to shutdown. It didn't boot since.

My video card is nVidia GeForce GT 130M.

Comment: It usually happens if the video card driver is in conflict with the kernel. What video card do you use? Did this happen right after you installed it? I once had a similar problem after a kernel upgrade, but I could still boot with the old kernel. (If the boot menu doesn't appear to you, then press ESC while booting.)

Comment: well .. i restarted twice and it worked fine, but when i tried to hibernate it, it didn't hibernate so i forced to shutdown ( by pressing the shutdown ) 
and didn't work since ! 
my video card is nvidia GeForce GT 130M . 

I tried  presseing ESC , nothing worked !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try booting up regularly and when it goes blank wait until you're sure that it's at the login screen.

Then hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 (in that order... well make sure you hit Ctrl+Alt before F1) to get into the command line mode. From there you can log in with your username and password to run apt-get upgrade, update, etc., and to remove your video card driver or replace it, etc.

Ctrl+Alt+F7 is the key combo to get back into the graphical mode.

Just be sure that if you do start up the PC that you don't just hard shut it down. Doing so can introduce errors into your OS that won't be very fun to diagnose or fix!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.04 is still [Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Beta) ... if you want to use Ubuntu for everyday use and not just testing download [Ubuntu 9.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download) .

Comment: Yea , i have it , but i just wanted to test 10.04 and its interface is really nice !  

too bad it just went black on me ! However it happend with 9.10 before , but when i re-installed it worked fine !

Answer (score 1):

I just booted up with an external monitor attached to my HP elitebook 8440p with this problem and the desktop came up on the monitor.  I enabled the proprietary nvidia drivers and rebooted to a functioning laptop panel.

Answer (score 1):

Did the problem start when you allowed Ubuntu to install your nVidia driver?

If so, here's what worked for me: **Download the driver from the nVidia site directly and try installing that.**

When I installed the driver provided by Ubuntu my machine kept booting to a blank, black screen; but when I downloaded and installed the driver from their site myself, it worked great.

Be sure to read the directions carefully. The basic process goes like this:

1. Boot to X-Windows (you may have to select Recovery Mode from the GRUB loader screen and then choose the option to start X in Failsafe mode)
2. Connect to the Internet, open Firefox, visit http://www.nvidia.com and download the Linux driver for your video adapter
3. Quit X-Windows; I did this by typing `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` (I'm no expert, there may be a better way -- you could probably just log out and press Ctrl-Alt-F2)
4. Login and browse to your download folder, then `chmod 755` the installer
5. Execute the installer script
6. Follow the directions

Answer (score 0):

Boot as single user. Then `apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade`.  Then install the nVidia driver, or the [nouveau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_%28graphics%29) driver, or whatever.

For help on single user see: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/-

Basically: in grub, add the linux boot parameter 'single', then give the root password.  If you don't have a root password set up you can boot with `init=/bin/sh`.

Comment: i tried to install the driver when i was logged in , but it didn't work ! 

plus i tried logging in by any means and it didn't work at all !