# Tmp directory deleted, I cannot login to the system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, recovery-console

I missinput a command in a directory (I don't remember what it is. Maybe it's in my `home/user/`, or in the `/` directory) in Ubuntu Linux.

```
sudo rm -f -r tmp
```

After that, when I restart and log in, I cannot login when I use that user. The system says some config file is missing for some apps I don't know in Gnome.

However, I can log in with user `root`.

Can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As root, do this:

```
# mkdir /tmp
# chmod o+t,ugo+rw /tmp
```

Comment: Worth noting that for selinux systems, you'll also want to run `restorecon /tmp`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot Dennis Williamson! Just in order to make the answer more detailed:

While you are in the login screen, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (do it in the same order) to switch to the command mode interface. From there you can login with your username and passwrod. then run:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get upgrade
# sudo rm -Rf /tmp
# mkdir /tmp #or if it didn't work run: sudo mkdir /tmp
# sudo chmod o+t,ugo+rw /tmp
# exit
```

Then restart your computer. It worked for me :)

You may also have a look
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/127713/ubuntu-10-04-is-not-booting-and-turns-to-blank-screen-cannot-login).

Comment: What is the deal with the apt-get update and apt-get upgrade? These commands have nothing to do with recreating the /tmp directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add more information about this problem, since it bugged me for many hours. I would never imagine that directory /tmp is so important in Ubuntu.

You can also spot this problem if you open the file (/var/log/auth.log)
and search for some lines similar to these:

```
Jan 18 01:55:12 localhost **gnome-keyring-daemon**[2016]: couldn't create socket directory: **Permission denied**
Jan 18 01:55:12 localhost gnome-keyring-daemon[2016]: couldn't bind to control socket: /tmp/keyring-mKRg6t/control: **No such file or directory**
Jan 18 01:55:12 localhost lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user <your_username>
```

This must have happened because you probably changed the permissions of directory /tmp.
And this is why you could login with root and not with other users.
As Dennis Williamson wrote this command (sudo chmod o+t,ugo+rw /tmp)
sets the correct permissions (drwxrwxrwt)